# Is there a quick way to get the typescript compiler source working in Visual Studio

Tags: typescript

I would like to do a bit of educational debugging inside the typesctipt compiler, but getting it to work in visual studio appears to be a bit trickier then I would have thought.

I tried creating a project and adding the compiler source file to a Visual Studio project but that gets me hundreds of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the `typescript.ts` file in `src/compiler` folder with visual studio and you will get the typeScript Compiler project.

Comment: Yes ... it sort of works except that the 0.9.5 version of the compiler generates an error when generating source maps for some of the files in the compiler :(. If I uncheck that option it works ... 10x for the help though :)